# Jenkins - j_acegi_security_check

Tags: authentication, tomcat, continuous-integration, installation, jenkins

I am trying to setup jenkins, but I cant get the authentication to work. I am running jenkins on Tomcat6 on CentOS 6.2. I enable logging in, and everything goes fine until I try to log in. After giving my credential and pressing login, tomcat gives me a error:

"HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource () is not available." on http://myserver:8080/jenkins/j_acegi_security_check

By googling I can find this:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3761

Two suggested fixes I have found:

- Run jenkins on tomcat instead of running the standalone version - I
  am already doing so.
- Edit a file:  WEB-INF/security/SecurityFilters.groovy - I tried to
  edit, but I can't get it to change anything

Is there something I could do to make this work?

Comment: FWIW It started happening to me lately that i was redirected to `j_acegi_security_check` blank page on login attempt, on Chrome and Opera on Windows. Turns out the problem was I had a *Fiddler proxy enabled* which for some reason was preventing me from logging in.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Spent ages wrestling with this one, make sure a Security Realm is set when you are choosing your Authorization method in Jenkins.

That is, in *Manage Jenkins → Configure Global Security* select an option in the *Security Realm* list.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Solved my issue, too. I was not *understanding* what was happening.

Answer (score 22):

You may have forgotten to select a Security Realm as specified below

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup

In case you have locked yourself out, you can revert the Jenkins config.xml file to set `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` node value to `false` by following instructions here

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned on [the bug page](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3761):

> The error was caused by a proxy pass rule `"/jenkins http://localhost:9080/jenkins/"` which led to the incomming (jenkins) request `"/jenkins//j_acegi_security_check"` (double //). So the login page was rejected with 404 (while all other pages where served).

Make sure your `/jenkins` ProxyPass does not end with a trailing slash in the destination URL.

Comment: I don't think that's the only issue, as it was fixed installing jenkins differently. I'm not sure if it even was behind a proxy at that point. EDIT: I'm not 100% certain on that though, comparing the date to a question of mine on serverfault, that could have been it. Can't verify my specific case so won't select the answer, but have an upvote

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on Ubuntu as well as on AIX, where I desperately needed it to work in production settings. I even tried Tomcat and Apache web servers, still the same issue.

Finally changing the class loader as follows made it work in stand-alone mode:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=79802 --preferredClassLoader=java.net.URLClassLoader &
```

By the way, this is default settings in standard Jenkins distribution for Ubuntu, from where I got the clue.

Probably the issue is related with packaging, but for now this solution works. Check if this resolves similar issues.

Comment: The machine which had the problem does not exist anymore, but thanks for telling this, as it might be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same HTTP 404 on the "/jenkins/j_acegi_security_check" URI problem .

And the same issue as pointed out by pga above: Tomcat was being started as user root.

This was because I had setup tomcat to restart automatically by creating a startup tomcat script at "/etc/init.d/".

Fixed the issue with:

```
su - tomcatuser - c /cde/pkgs/../tomcat/start.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with 404 on the "/jenkins/j_acegi_security_check" page.

Using Jenkins with Tomcat, after a lot of tries to solve it, I came to following solution - I´m using 18080 as default port without SSL-redirection.
It´s related to the redirection, but in that case (as using Tomcat) it has to be changed in the tomcat-server-configuration:

Look in **/conf/server.xml** for the following entry:

```
<Connector port="18080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

Just commenting out the **redirectPort** helped for me:

```
<Connector port="18080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My bookmarked jenkins login url was: https://jenkins.foo.com/login?from=%2F

If security is disabled and you hit that url with any credentials or blank ones, it brings up the j_acegi error.

Instead, use https://jenkins.foo.com/ and it will take you straight to the dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same HTTP 404 on the "/jenkins/j_acegi_security_check" URI.

In my case, Jenkins was running on a Tomcat started by user 'root'. Stopped Tomcat, and started it again by the proper separate application user.  Problem solved.

Comment: It could have been running as root, as it was a service installed by yum. I thought I configured it to run as something else though...

Answer (score -1):

Seeing vote down: I did the steps again on fresh server.
There were ** characters and I removed that

There were missing $sign for tomcat like this $TOMCAT_VERSION

## (Both corrected and it is working) (updated on 28.03.2016)

Disable the security as given below:

http://markunsworth.com/2012/02/13/locked-yourself-out-of-jenkins/

Unable to login jenkins, and can't disable login option either
Or
Locked in login with Jenkins on Tomcat.

`http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/jenkins/login?from=/jenkins/` and after filling the userId Password, which was not set up at all, will always take to this page

```
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/jenkins/j_acegi_security_check
```

HTTP Status 404 - description The requested resource is not available.

I had .war file installed in tomcat
It took me long to fix this issue.
I had many times completely removed Tomcat, Jenkins all folders .jenkins etc reinstalled and what not...

Remove both Tomcat and Jenkins completely once again...

***The solution is proper use of user and group, let us see how to it by running the following commands one by one.***

You are logged in with user(e.g. vimal) with sudo permission.

```
 vimal@h123:~$ sudo apt-get update
 vimal@h123:~$ BASE_USER=vimal
 vimal@h123:~$ sudo chown -Rf $BASE_USER:$BASE_USER /opt/

 vimal@h123:~$ USER=apache-tomcat
 vimal@h123:~$ GROUP=myjenkins
 vimal@h123:~$ TOMCAT_INSTALL_DIR=/opt
 vimal@h123:~$ TOMCAT_VERSION=apache-tomcat-8.0.23
 vimal@h123:~$ TOMCAT_URL=http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.23/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.23.zip
```

For TOMCAT_URL, copy the link that you need from archive/src (.zip) of tomcat download site

```
vimal@h123:~$ mkdir -p $TOMCAT_INSTALL_DIR
vimal@h123:~$ cd $TOMCAT_INSTALL_DIR
vimal@h123:~$ wget $TOMCAT_URL
vimal@h123:~$ unzip -q $TOMCAT_VERSION.zip
vimal@h123:~$ rm $TOMCAT_VERSION.zip
```

Before running command below you need to have JAVA_HOME set up in like JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/" by adding this into 
    **sudo nano  /etc/environment**

```
vimal@h123:~$ sudo chmod +x  $TOMCAT_INSTALL_DIR/$TOMCAT_VERSION/bin/*.sh
vimal@h123:~$ $TOMCAT_INSTALL_DIR/$TOMCAT_VERSION/bin/catalina.sh start
vimal@h123:~$
vimal@h123:~$ cd $TOMCAT_INSTALL_DIR/$TOMCAT_VERSION/webapps/
vimal@h123:~$ wget http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/war-stable/latest/jenkins.war
```

Wait for a couple of minutes till Jenkins is fully loaded. Needs 2GB memory.
Try going to the browser on http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/jenkins/ and it will work...

Took me one day to find the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I resolved this issue:

```
# service tomcat status
tomcat start/running, process 996

# service tomcat stop
tomcat stop/waiting

# service jenkins status
Jenkins Continuous Integration Server is not running

# service jenkins restart
 * Restarting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server jenkins                [ OK ]
# service tomcat start
tomcat start/running, process 3839

# service jenkins status
Jenkins Continuous Integration Server is running with the pid 3694
```

Refresh your  browser and Jenkins should be up and running. 
Hope this helps!